# What are the odds of picking a jack, queen, and king from a deck of cards, in that order?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm  being thrown off by the fact they have to be in that order, would the answer be

${4\over 52}$ x ${4\over 51}$ x ${4\over 50}$

I've handled problems like this similarly, except they did not state that "order matters." Help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

52 cards in a deck of which 4 are jacks, 4 are queens, and 4 are kings.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  If the order of them did not matter, then the answer would be six times as large.  As a typesetting note, `\times` produces $\times$ or `\cdot` produces $\cdot$ for multiplication.